# ANSI Warnings on Amazon RDS SQL Server not setting

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I have strange problem in an AWS RDS SQL Server database I have spun up and I can't figure out what is going on.

**Test 1**

```
create table #tmp  
(test varchar(10) null)  

insert into #tmp  
select 'asfsadfasdsafdafas'

select * from #tmp  
drop table #tmp
```

Results in:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 5
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> (0 row(s) affected)

**Test 2**

```
set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF  

create table #tmp1  
(test varchar(10) null)  

insert into #tmp1  
select 'asfsadfasdsafdafas'  

select * from #tmp1  
drop table #tmp1
```

Results in:

```
------------------ 
asfsadfasd
```

When I look at the database properties it says that ANSI Warnings Enabled is set to FALSE, however, the database does not appear to be behaving as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Another Example might help

```
ALTER DATABASE test_db   
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF  
go  

select "hello"
```

Results in:

> ---
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Invalid column name 'hello'.

Thanks

Comment: Almost all clients (e.g. ADO, ODBC, etc) will set ansi_warnings on by default. I'd strongly recommend leaving it on anyway - if you want truncation to occur here, it's easy enough to specify a `SUBSTRING` operation. And a lot of SQL Server functionality just plain isn't available if ansi warnings are turned off, so it's a bad habit to get into of developing code that requires them off.

Comment: For reference http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SET+Options/144571/

Comment: Thanks Damien - I would love it if I could do that. Unfortunately it's not an option for us. I'm migrating an existing server to AWS and I need to replicate it as is. I also have a similar issue with quoted_identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    --The Issue Occur Because of Length Of Datatype 

    create table #tmp1  
    (test varchar(50) null)  

    insert into #tmp1  
    select 'asfsadfasdsafdafas'  

    select * from #tmp1  
    drop table #tmp1 
--==============================

When create or alter SQL object like Stored Procedure, User Defined Function in Query Analyzer, it is created with following SQL commands prefixed and suffixed. What are these – QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON/OFF and ANSI_NULL ON/OFF?
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO--SQL PROCEDURE, SQL FUNCTIONS, SQL OBJECTGO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

ANSI NULL ON/OFF:
This option specifies the setting for ANSI NULL comparisons. When this is on, any query that compares a value with a null returns a 0. When off, any query that compares a value with a null returns a null value.

QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON/OFF:
This options specifies the setting for usage of double quotation. When this is on, double quotation mark is used as part of the SQL Server identifier (object name). This can be useful in situations in which identifiers are also SQL Server reserved words.
```

Comment: Thanks Affaiz -  I'll rephrase my question a bit

Comment: Thanks - I need to be able to set this at the database level i.e so that it persists beyond that session

Comment: Right click The DB >>OPTIONS >>Quoted Identifiers Enabled ON/OFF